# how to uninstall ubuntu 10.10

Tags: 10.10, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I felt I will get two operating systems (Windows XP installed) when I  install Ubuntu 10.10 it displays only Ubuntu I'm not getting my previous OS.

Please tell me how to uninstall Ubuntu 10.10 and to get my previous OS.

Answer (score 1):

First check to see that your windows partion are not deleted. this could have happened if during installation you selected to use the full disk. If they are still there you could insert the windows cd and do a repair installation.

Follow one of these links:
[MS](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true)

This may help to edit the grub to include the windows installation if the partion is still there [Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1655655)